SpecSync unable to find test results in .trx test results file
I'm trying to figure out how to work SpecSync.
https://docs.specsolutions.eu/specsync/reference/command-line-reference/push-command
I tried publishing this test results file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

I think something is wrong with the format. I get this error whenever I try and publish this file.
  No test results found in this file.

No test results found in any of the processed files.
Any suggestions?
